# Evaluating the integral $\int\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ via substitution

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle\int\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

I know you take $u = \sqrt{x} \Rightarrow du = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} dx \Rightarrow 2du = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Then you would have $2\displaystyle\int e^u du = 2e^u + C = 2e^{\sqrt{x}}+C$.

Here is my question. When you let $u = \sqrt{x}$, then wouldn't be $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^{u}}{u} du$ since $u$ is being substituted for $\sqrt{x}$. Why do we not have to do that in this problem?

Comment: Why do you think they computed $du$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but because you also have to express $dx$ in terms of $u$ and $du$, that is to say, $$dx = 2 \sqrt{x} \, du = 2u \, du,$$ you could write $$\int \frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = \int \frac{e^u}{u} \cdot 2u \, du = 2 \int e^u \, du,$$ and you see that the $u$ in the denominator cancels out.

You can also see this by observing that if we set $u = \sqrt{x}$, this implies $x = u^2$, thus $dx = 2u \, du$ as we found above.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like that then $dx=2\sqrt{x}du=2udu$ as we also need to change $d()$( the wrt part) so $u$ just cancels leading to same integral as evaluated before

Comment: this is wrong see my comment  above